# How to wrap Kendo Grid Column

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo Grid columns is given as below. After doing zoom screen column is getting hide, I want to do wrap column. Can we do it by giving some propery on gridColumns. Please tell me. I am not able to find it. Here 'Your Occupation Details' is getting hide. Here are some more fields, I have given only three here.

```
 gridColumns: [
            {
                title: 'FirstName',
                field: 'FirstName',
                width: '0', hidden: true
            },
            {
                title: 'FirstName',
                field: 'FirstName',
                width: '250px'
            },
            {
                title: 'Your Occupation Details',
                field: 'OccupationDetails',
                width: '100',
            }]
```

Answer (score 27):

Use headerAttributes to wrap long column names in the JS columns declaration as follows;

```
columns: [
{
  title: 'Your Occupation Details',
  field: 'OccupationDetails',
  width: '100',
  headerAttributes: { style: "white-space: normal"}
},
...
]
```

Or for strongly typed grids you can use HeaderHtmlAttributes in Columns as well.

```
columns.Bound(p => p.OccupationDetails).HeaderHtmlAttributes(
    new { style = "white-space: normal" }
);
```

Further documentation can be found in the Telerik's official forum [Header Wrapping / Height](http://www.telerik.com/forums/header-wrapping-height) and [How to wrap kendo grid column](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-wrap-kendo-grid-column)

Comment: @user1078749 I do not know why this is not the answer already?

Answer (score 20):

You can set CSS properties of the Grid to enable column wrap.

```
.k-grid-header .k-header {
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Take a look at this documentation for setting column header attributes.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.headerAttributes

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me

```
.k-grid  .k-grid-header  .k-header  .k-link {
    height: auto;
}
```

and this

```
.k-grid  .k-grid-header  .k-header {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

source: http://www.telerik.com/forums/header-wrapping-height

Answer (score 5):

To wrap the header:

```
.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header .k-link { height: auto; }

.k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header { white-space: normal; }
```

To wrap the rows:

```
td[role="gridcell"] { white-space: nowrap; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
   .k-grid .k-grid-header .k-header .k-link {
      overflow: visible !important; white-space: normal !important; 
   }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add this to your custom CSS if you need to the warp text of the column header of a specific grid. This worked for me.

```
#yourgrid .k-grid-header  .k-header .k-link {
    white-space: normal !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
   k-grid  .k-grid-header  .k-header  .k-link {
    height: auto;
    word-break:break-all !important;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
}
.k-grid  .k-grid-header  .k-header {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

Works Perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following `css` to you code, it will be applied to all grid columns and you won't need to add style attribute to individual grid column.

```
<style>
    .k-grid td {
        word-break: break-all !important;
        word-wrap: break-word !important;
    }
</style>
```